# How do i change to boot from host partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, swap

I am currently partitioning my disk for LFS build while my host system being Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After I finished with the partitioning, I rearranged partitions with  `gdsik /dev/sdb` command followed by the 's' option, to reorder the partition. After reboot, I was brought to boot manager with the message "HDD/SSD is failed." Then I booted up from live cd to see what's the matter, and saw that the boot loader changed to swap partition:

Partition table

[image: img_Partition_table]

Please help me, i need the system to boot from the HOST partition, that being Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *By LFS I assume you mean Linux from Scratch but it's best if you're specific*

Comment: @guiverc whats the problem with my question? i see it on topic

Comment: I see only mention of an off-topic OS, and nothing on-topic as per my initial comment.  The only OS you mention (as per my first comment) is covered by SE *Unix & Linux* as it's not Ubuntu, or *flavor* of Ubuntu - again refer my first comment.

Comment: i am sorry but my question isnt about that off-topic OS i mentioned, its about partitioning my ubuntu host system. I can't boot up on my Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Edit your question providing OS & release details, as currently I see only mention of off-topic...  (also release details of the *live* might help, some *live* systems auto-mount swap partitions when detected - thus the *lock* symbol you see, but you've provided no release details so we can't currently speak with authority that matches your system as we don't know what that is; esp. release details)

Comment: @guiverc i edited my question, is this good enough?

Comment: Your swap partition is locked because it is in use by the life session. The key has nothing to do with boot loaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

From what you have told us there is a fair probability that your /etc/fstab file uses the partition numbers (eg /dev/sdb1 etc...) to mount things correctly. See the manual for gdisk:

-s
Sort partition entries. GPT partition numbers need not match the order of partitions on the disk. If you want them to match, you can use this option. Note that some partitioning utilities sort partitions whenever they make changes. Such changes will be reflected in your device filenames, so you may need to edit /etc/fstab if you use this option.

To edit your /etc/fstab file boot into a live environment, mount sdb4, and edit with your preferred editor

Comment: thanks, it finally clicked what i was doing wrong